# AlethZero browser won't connect to the internet

Tags: browsers, alethzero

When I launch AlethZero, the program starts seemingly fine. The browser included, from my understanding, should be able to browse the internet like any other browser. However, when I type `www.google.com`, it returns the following error:

```
"Error downloading DApp: " Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION)
Dynamic exception type: struct dev::Exception
std::exception::what: Unknown exception
[struct dev::tag_comment *__ptr64] = Dapp content hash does not match
```

Ok. So maybe it's looking for a DApp that doesn't exist.

When I type `http://google.com` or `http://www.google.com`, I get this error:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

These combinations of errors are thrown for any variety of websites I try. I am very new to all of this and would like to know how to get AlethZero's browser to work. I am on Windows x64 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The browser included, from my understanding, should be able to browse the internet like any other browser.

I am afraid that you have misunderstood the aim of the software. As is the case with the Mist (Ethereum Wallet) browser, these tools are for hosting distributed apps (dapps) and may use web technologies, but they are not general web browsers.

You can get a [glimpse into the future](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgNjs_WaFSc), which shows what the Mist Dapp Browser is intended to become within the next few months.   So the user-experience would be similar to a web browser (hence the name), but you would be browsing and interacting with dapps, not with existing web content.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I was following the tutorial at this site: `https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/your-first-dapp/`, and it led me to believe one could browse the internet. I suppose it could be an outdated article.

Comment: True, I'm reading the same tutorial and it explicitly says "At the centre of the screen is a browser window, a Webkit view to be exact. You can browse the existing web from there, just like any other browser, try Google for example." But when I try to type google.com in what looks like an address bar and hit Enter, nothing happens, not even an error. It gets me worried about whether I set up the tools correctly and can move forward with the tutorial.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you contact the author of that blog post and point out the issue.    It must just be old info.